# How to insert space between alphabet characters and numeric character using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to insert space between numeric characters and alphabet character so I can convert numeric character to words like :

```
Input : 
     subject101
     street45
Output :
     subject 101
     street 45
```

I tried this one

```
re.sub('[a-z][\d]|[\d][a-z]',' ','subject101')
```

but the output was like this :

```
subjec 01
```

How can I do it using python?

Comment: Did you attempt something?

Comment: yes, I tried this one `re.sub('[a-z][\d]|[\d][a-z]',' ',line)` but it deleted some the first digits too

Comment: Good, add that to you question. It will also allow us to help you understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?i)(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW1u5r/1/)**

Replace each match with a space

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - modifier to make the matches case-insensitive
- `(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])` - finds the position just preceded by a digit and followed by a letter
- `|` - OR
- `(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)` - finds the position just preceded by a letter and followed by a digit

[**Code output**](http://rextester.com/TXP3246)

```
import re
regex = r"(?i)(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)"
test_str = ("subject101\n"
    "     street45")
subst = " "
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this would be to pass a callable to `re.sub`. This allows you to reuse the matched substring to generate the replacement value.

```
subject = '101subject101'

s = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]\d|\d[a-zA-Z]', lambda m: ' '.join(m.group()), subject )
# s: '101 subject 101'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use if statement `(?(#group))` in regex to check if char is digit or a letter.

**Regex**: [`(?<=([a-z])|\d)(?=(?(1)\d|[a-z]))`](https://regex101.com/r/EIhtP7/1)

Python code:

```
def addSpace(text):
    return re.sub(r'(?<=([a-z])|\d)(?=(?(1)\d|[a-z]))', ' ', text)
```

Output:

```
addSpace('subject101')
>>> subject 101
addSpace('101subject')
>>> 101 subject
```